# Can't compile App from Titanium Appcelerator with iOS OpenCV Module

Tags: xcode, opencv, titanium, appcelerator

I have an issue that is going on for over a month and I can't find any solution for it.
I created an Appcelerator Titanium Module, which uses the OpenCV framework.
I tried literally everything I found on the internet to make it work, but no sucess.
The module compiles, but it crashes when building the App that uses it.
To dig deep in the problem, I compile the App via `CLI` using `appc run -p ios -l trace` to see the whole thing. This is what I get:

`[TRACE] ld: framework not found opencv2 [TRACE] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

This happens if I declare the framework in the `module.xconfig` file, like this:

`OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework opencv2`

If I don't declare it in the file, I get:

`[TRACE] symbols not found for architecture x86_64 [TRACE] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Well, the `opencv2.framework` file is inside the `/ios` folder in the module.

This is what I tried so far, to put the `OpenCV Framework` in the project:

[OpenCV Official Example for XCode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d88/tutorial_hello.html)

[Compiling it from scratch and then adding to the Project](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/da3/tutorial_ios_install.html)

`brew install opencv and then adding it to the project`

I configured `Framework Search Paths` like this:

`$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR) $(SRCROOT)`

`Header Search Paths` like this:

`$(inherited) "$(TITANIUM_SDK)/iphone/include" /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.4.0/include` (this last one, when installed by `brew CLI command`.

The `Other Linker Flags`, is configured like this:

[image: This configuration I got from the Tutorial below]

This configuration I got from this tutorial: [OpenCV on XCode](https://www.codementor.io/@ohasanli/opencv-on-xcode-142qxx3sl8)

And finally, I tried adding the `.dylib` files from the source of the `OpenCV Framework` in the project by right-clicking the project's name and Add Files.

So, I tried everything I could find to solve it, but I can't get it to work.
Sorry for the long question, but I am completly out of ideas on how to make this work.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `opencv2.framework` is copied automatically to the XCode `/ios` folder (if you selected Copy Files if Needed). BUT, Appcelerator needs 3rd party frameworks to be put on `/ios/platform` folder. So, I moved it there.

Secondly I added `-lz` to the `Other Linker Flags` in `Build Settings`.

This solved the problem. I must thank the team and developers from `TiSlack` (An Appcelerator platform community), which helped me through this. Michael and Hans, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video that helped me install OpenCV4 on my Macbook Pro Mojave 10.14.6. I tried installing OpenCV using another video and it led me to getting a linker error that was similar to yours.

Basically, the problem was the path I specified as for my /lib and /include folders.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?edufilter=NULL&v=HxNZEa7Slyk

Comment: Thanks! I already solved my problem, but I will keep this video saved for the future.